# How to change all occurrences of one character in a group of filenames with another?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I have some OS X files, some of which have hyphens in their filenames. I want to change all occurrences of hyphens to underscores.

How can I do this from the command line on OS X?

So, if I have this:

```
a.txt
b-c.txt
d_e-f.txt
```

I'd like to rename them to this:

```
a.txt
b_c.txt
d_e_f.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash, use simple [substring replacement](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), and replace all occurrences of `-` with `_`.

```
for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "${f//-/_}"; done
```

The loop will iterate over each `.txt` file in the current directory.